# WP7 ToggleSwitch to SQL

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to save the result from a ToggleSwitch (True/False) back to my Azure Database through a WCF. Within the database, the datatype is set to int.

Is that correct so far?

Then I dont know what follows the toggle1. part of this code, eg:

```
        private void addPersonBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       _ServiceClient.AddPersonAsync(fnameTxtBox.Text, snameTxtBox.Text, toggle1.XXX, toggle2.XXX);
    }
```

Again, what would go here - unfortunately its not limiting it to a few options, but quite a long list on the autocomplete.

Any help would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: What is the `AddPersonAsync` method signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IsChecked` property is what you're looking for. It's a boolean  (`bool?` , or `Nullable<bool>`) value you can use to indicate whether the switch is checked.

If your method signature takes `bool`, you can use `toggle1.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault()`, to get the checked state, or `false` if the value is `null`. I'm almost positive `ToggleSwitch` will always have a true/false value, though.

Comment: Thanks, seems to be working now (or accepting it at least. Still have some other errors to fix before I can do a test.
+1